# Override assumed extension in compiling with pdflatex

Tags: graphics, external-files

I compile all my latex documents using `pdflatex`. Now, I have a bunch of figures from some simulations with filenames of the style of `fig1_N32s5.0t0.5.pdf`. If I do

```
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{fig1_N32s5.0t0.5.pdf}
```

en error arises because of unrecognized file format. How does one override this? I don't want to change my clasification of my figures, since to me the filename is very adequate.

Comment: Easiest solution: Put braces around the name: `\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{{fig1_N32s5.0t0.5}.pdf}`.

Comment: grffile with option multidot should work, but I would avoid multidots, it is not garantied to be portable between texsystems and OS.

Comment: How does it work if the files are in another location? E.g. `../../fig1_N32s5.0t0.5.pdf`

Comment: `../../{fig.zzz}.pdf` should work, most likely

Comment: Yup, I didn't had the filenames that pdflatex was looking for.